# Monitoring Kubernetes cluster using prometheus outside the k8 cluster

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus

- We have kubernetes cluster where I have service account "kube", namespace "monitoring" with cluster role binding created to monitor cluster
- We have prometheus installed on a linux system (on prem) outside the cluster and is installed using "root"
- When I try to connect to the k8 cluster with the https api using `ca.crt` and user `token` (given by kubernetes admin), it throws multiple errors.

Error messages:

```
component="discovery manager scrape" msg="Cannot create service discovery" err="unable to use specified CA cert /root/prometheus/ca.crt" type=*kubernetes.SDConfig

component="discovery manager scrape" msg="Cannot create service discovery" err="unable to use specified CA cert /root/prometheus/ca.crt" type=*kubernetes.SDConfig
```

Prometheus configuration:

```
  - job_name: 'kubernetes-apiservers'
    scheme: https
    tls_config:
      ca_file: /root/prometheus/ca.crt
    bearer_token_file: /root/prometheus/user_token
    kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: endpoints
      api_server: https://example.com:1234
      bearer_token_file: /root/prometheus/user_token
      tls_config:
        ca_file: /root/prometheus/prometheus-2.12.0.linux-amd64/ca.crt
    relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [monitoring, monitoring-sa, 6443]
      action: keep
      regex: default;kubernetes;https

  - job_name: 'kubernetes-nodes'
    scheme: https
    tls_config:
        ca_file: /root/prometheus/ca.crt
    bearer_token_file: /root/prometheus/user_token

    kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: node
      api_server: https://example.com:1234
      bearer_token_file: /root/prometheus/user_token
      tls_config:
        ca_file: /root/prometheus/ca.crt
    relabel_configs:
    - action: labelmap
      regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
    - target_label: __address__
      replacement: https://example.com:1234
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
      regex: (.+)
      target_label: __metrics_path__
      replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}/proxy/metrics
```

Comment: What is the version of Prometheus?

Comment: 2.12.0 @KamolHasan

Comment: @KamolHasan same error with 2.13.1

Answer (score 2):

The main problem you're facing is: `"unable to use specified CA cert /root/prometheus/ca.crt"`

Someone recently faced the same problem:
https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/6015#issuecomment-532058465

He solved it by reinstalling the new version.

Version `2.13.1` is out. Try installing the latest version, it might solve your problem too.

Comment: I can try that ....but since i am very new to prometheus, can you tell me what all is required to connect to k8 cluster from external prometheus (for now using user_token and ca.crt ). 


The link you provided is using ca_file, cert_file, key_file , do i also need to use all of them.

Lastly, does my configuration looks good?

Answer (score 2):

Your `ca.crt` is most probably still in `base64` format since secrets are encoded that way when describing them, as explained [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#service-account-tokens).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your `ca.crt` have some error, check your ca cert file, make sure this file format like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I think your `ca.crt` is get by `kubectl get serviceaccount -o yaml`, but this is a public key with your kubernetes cluster, so, if you want to get the token, you can specify the `serviceAccountName` in the yaml file with a new `Deployment`, like this:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
        version: v1
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: prometheus
      containers:
      - name: test
        image: alpine
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command: ["ping", "127.0.0.1"]
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: harbor-secret
      restartPolicy: Always
```

Then, get your `token` and `ca.crt` under `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/`.